# passing arguments to Python Class

Tags: python, pyspark

I have created one Python class to parse the text Input File in order to have a file in CSV format.
Below is my class code:

```
import os
from os import listdir

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, filename, colsList):
        self.filename=filename
        self.colsList=colsList

    def textcsvconverter(self,filename,colsList):
        import csv
        print("colsList:",colsList)
        self.cols=colsList
        outputfilename=(os.path.basename(filename))
        print("outputfilename:",outputfilename)
        fname_out =(outputfilename + '.csv')
        with open(filename) as fin, open(fname_out, 'wt') as fout:
            writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n")
            for line in fin:
                line = line.rstrip()  # removing the '\n' and other trailing whitespaces
                data = [line[c[0]:c[1]] for c in cols]
                writer.writerow(data)
            return fname_out
```

Now I have imported this class in my Pyspark code and trying to access the class method as shown below:

```
myobjectx = MyClass()
colsListA = [(0,1), (1,23), (23,31), (31,35),(35,41)]
outputfile1=myobjectx.textcsvconverter(finalpath1,colsListA)
```

Its giving me below error message:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Both `filename` and `colsList` are mandatory arguments. You should provide its values while instantiating the object . (ie, **myobjectx = MyClass(your_filename, you_colsList**) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declare your class with init method with 3 arguments. but you have input it. As you code show, you can get a default value in the init method.

```
def __init__(self, filename=None, colsList=[]):
    self.filename=filename
    self.colsList=colsList
```

So, that you can declare your instance without put any argument into it.

```
myobjectx = MyClass()
```

And, you can lazy assign or put argument in like you are doing with `textcsvconverter` method now.

**UPDATE**

As your comment below, I can see you are trying to make an instance of your class with a certain input :

```
finalpath1 = 'your-filename.csv' # I assume you have it
colsListA = [(0,1), (1,23), (23,31), (31,35),(35,41)] 
myobjectx = MyClass(finalpath1,colsListA)
outputfile1=myobjectx.textcsvconverter()
```

And you have to update your `textcsvconverter` to use your self.attribute.

Comment: This is how I am calling my class now   

colsListA = [(0,1), (1,23), (23,31), (31,35),(35,41)]
myobjectx = MyClass(finalpath1,colsListA)
outputfile1=myobjectx.textcsvconverter()   

I am getting below error message
    self.colsList=cols
NameError: global name 'cols' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you took the two arguments in init method. that's the reason, you will get the error.

```
 TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

The solution is, you should change your init method something like this.

```
def __init__(self, filename=None, colsList=[]):
    self.filename=filename
    self.colsList=colsList
```

OR

```
colsListA = [(0,1), (1,23), (23,31), (31,35),(35,41)]
myobjectx = MyClass(finalpath1, colsListA)
outputfile1=myobjectx.textcsvconverter(finalpath1,colsListA)
```

In the above second case, you need to modify your whole code.

```
import os
from os import listdir

class MyClass:
def __init__(self, filename, colsList):
    self.filename=filename
    self.colsList=colsList

def textcsvconverter(self):
    import csv
    print("colsList:",self.colsList)
    self.cols=self.colsList
    outputfilename=(os.path.basename(self.filename))
    print("outputfilename:",outputfilename)
    fname_out =(outputfilename + '.csv')
    with open(self.filename) as fin, open(fname_out, 'wt') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n")
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip()  # removing the '\n' and other trailing    whitespaces
            data = [line[c[0]:c[1]] for c in cols]
            writer.writerow(data)
        return fname_out


  colsListA = [(0,1), (1,23), (23,31), (31,35),(35,41)]
  myobjectx = MyClass(finalpath1,colsListA)
  outputfile1=myobjectx.textcsvconverter()
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I have made the changes as suggested.
I am getting below error now:   data = [line[c[0]:c[1]] for c in cols]
NameError: global name 'cols' is not defined.. This is how I am calling through Pyspark colsListA = [(0,1), (1,23), (23,31), (31,35),(35,41)]
myobjectx = MyClass(finalpath1,colsListA)
outputfile1=myobjectx.textcsvconverter()

Answer (score 0):

Its working now after a small change :-)  cols=self.colsList Thanks all for your help and support